# elasticsearch / solr search in ezpublish 2014.11

Tags: ezpublish

Using `eZ Publish community 2014.11`, I'd like to index contents in Elastic Search or Solr (or similar index engines) in order to :

- perform full text search on contents (with respect for access rights on contents, and object relations extraction)
- make custom calls to index in custom controllers to bypass mysql content repository limitations regarding sorting on different classes attributes

What is the prefered way of doing performing ezfind-like `2014.11` ?

Notes :

- I'm not using legacy stack and try to avoid it as much as possible in order to facilitate further migrations, but if I have to I'll use it.
- Currently, I'm planning to use this [intallation documentation ezfind LS 5.2](https://doc.ez.no/Extensions/eZ-Publish-extensions/eZ-Find/eZ-Find-LS-5.2.0/Installation)
- There is some activity around these question [here](https://jira.ez.no/browse/EZP-22944) and [here](https://jira.ez.no/browse/EZP-24358)
- there's a [bundle by netgen](https://github.com/netgen/netgensearchandfilterbundle)
- In previous versions I used to use ezfind for that which is available in `2014-11` distribution, but I also see elasticsearch bundles in this version. I quickly tried to use it but go the following errors :

```

```
php ezpublish/console ezpublish:elasticsearch_create_index --env=dev
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method eZPublishCorePersistenceLegacyContentSearchHandler_000000007c8f5baa000000006bdeda53::setCommit() in /var/www/ez5/vendor/ezsystems/ezpublish-kernel/eZ/Publish/Core/Persistence/Cache/SearchHandler.php on line 122
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/ez5/ezpublish/console:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /var/www/ez5/ezpublish/console:27
PHP   3. eZ\Bundle\EzPublishCoreBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/ez5/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:124
PHP   4. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/ez5/vendor/ezsystems/ezpublish-kernel/eZ/Bundle/EzPublishCoreBundle/Console/Application.php:41
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/ez5/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:96
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /var/www/ez5/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:193
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /var/www/ez5/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:896
PHP   8. eZ\Bundle\EzPublishElasticsearchBundle\Command\ElasticsearchCreateIndexCommand->execute() /var/www/ez5/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:252
PHP   9. eZ\Publish\Core\Persistence\Cache\SearchHandler->setCommit() /var/www/ez5/vendor/ezsystems/ezpublish-kernel/eZ/Bundle/EzPublishElasticsearchBundle/Command/ElasticsearchCreateIndexCommand.php:61
```

```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I found so far is to call ezFind from symfony as explained here :

http://share.ez.no/blogs/carlos-revillo/ez-find-with-symfony-controller-and-twig-templates